# Spring Data Repository for Entity where foreign key is also primary key

Tags: java, spring, jpa, foreign-key-relationship, spring-data-jpa

I have some problems with JPA2 (EclipseLink) and Spring Data 1.4.2.
In my case two tables has one-to-one relation:

TableA:

- aId (PK)
- ...

TableB:

- bId (PK, FK - maps to aId in TableA)
- ...

so I tried to do this entities:

EntityA:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableA")
public class EntityA implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "aId")
    private Long id;
    // another fields and getter/setter/business methods
    ... 
}
```

EntityB:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableB")
public class EntityB {
    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "bId", referencedColumnName = "aId")
    private EntityA id;
    // another fields and getter/setter/business methods
    ... 
}
```

Spring Data Repository for EntityA works well:

```
@Repository(value = "aRepository")
public interface RepositoryA extends CrudRepository<EntityA, Long> {
}
```

but for EntityB:

```
@Repository(value = "bRepository")
public interface RepositoryB extends PagingAndSortingRepository<EntityB, EntityA> {
}
```

throws Exception:

```
Expected id attribute type [class java.lang.Long] on the existing id attribute [SingularAttributeImpl[EntityTypeImpl@5270829:EntityA [....] but found attribute type [class EntityB].
```

Comment: Which class is raising the exception? I think the problem is the `OneToOne` annotation in `EntityB`, then `id` in `EntityA` is expected to be `EntityB` type.

Comment: Exception is thrown when container tries to instantiate bRepository bean.
I need just unidirectional mapping, so I thought that reverse link is not needed.

Comment: Try adding `@MapsId` to the `@OneToOne` annotation in `EntityB`: `@OneToOne @MapsId`.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ObjectAccessor.processMapsId(ObjectAccessor.java:542)

I don't know why and how  it  happened :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The annotation to use is `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`, not `@JoinColumn`:

> Specifies a primary key column that is used as a foreign key to join to another table.
>
> It is used to join the primary table of an entity subclass in the JOINED mapping strategy to the primary table of its superclass; it is used within a SecondaryTable annotation to join a secondary table to a primary table; **and it may be used in a OneToOne mapping in which the primary key of the referencing entity is used as a foreign key to the referenced entity**.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use this annotation earlier and saw description of its usage. But with this annotation instantiating Spring Data repository throws exception too :( Maybe the problem is in my lack of understanding of Spring Data?

Comment: I haven't used this annotation for a while. IIRC, you need another field, of type Long, annotated with `@Id`. And the ManyToOne shouldn't be annotated with `@Id`.

Comment: @chepiov why you marked it as an answer, since you report that spring data continue throwing exception?

Answer (score 4):

The main problem (the exception) is not about the use of `@JoinColumn` rather than `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`, but what must be a limit of current Spring Data (as of 1.7.1).
I also hit this problem and opened [DATAJPA-649](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-649) for it.
I couldn't find a workaround, rather than change the data model so that `EntityB` has a primary key independent from `EntityA`. The use of `@MapsId` does not help either.